# AS2 Procotol - Onehub XML Transfer on Windows Server With C#

Tags: c#, xml, actionscript-2, file-transfer

For data integration, I need to get IDOC XML files from Onehub with AS2 protocol to Windows Server. After that, I need to send some XML files to Onehub with AS2 protocol from Windows Server. I google it. There is some tools but I confused.

- How can I do it with C#?
- Am I need to like AS2 server or something?
- Can I do it only with C# Form Application?